# Fail with node.js Passport signup

Tags: node.js, passport.js, express-session

Iam building app with Node.js using Passport version 0.4.0 for sign up. But my post method doesnt work correctly, my user doesnt save into database. Here is my config/passport.js file:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) =>{
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Email is already used.'});
        }
        var newUser = new User();
        newUser.email = email;
        newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
        newUser.save(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, newUser);
        }); 
    });
}));
```

In my route/index.js file i identified my post and get methods:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const csrf = require('csurf');
    var passport = require('passport'); 

const Products = require('../models/product');
const Users = require('../models/user');

const productRouter = express.Router();

const csrfProtection = csrf();
productRouter.use(csrfProtection);

productRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
//Here my methods for product model
.........
.........
productRouter.get('/user/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('user/signup', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
});

productRouter.post('/user/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
    successRedirect: '/user/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/user/signup',
    failureFlash: true
}));

productRouter.get('/user/profile', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('user/profile');
});


module.exports = productRouter;
```

Im required in my app.js file session, passport and flash (app.js):

```
........
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
```

Then after connecting, i require my config/passport file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

const Products = require('./models/product');
const User = require('./models/user');

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mystore';
const connect = mongoose.connect(url, {
  useMongoClient: true
});

connect.then((db) => {
  console.log('Connected correctly to server');
}, (err) => { console.log(err); });

require('./config/passport');
```

Im created a signup.hbs template:

```
<form class="form" role="form" 
action="/user/signup" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email@gmail.com" required="">
         </div>
           <div class="form-group">
             <label for="password">Password</label>
             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password" required="">
            </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{ csrfToken }}">
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg float-right">Register</button>
            </div>
     </form>
```

Im correctly connected to the localhost:3000/user/signup, but after submitting the form nothing happend and my user collection is empty.

And of course my models/user.js model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');


var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

userSchema.methods.encryptPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(5), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};     

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Any ideas where im wrong?
much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Noob here but does handlebars allow you to form-post without name attributes in your inputs, have you validated thru chrome inspector those are being sent?